# Laser scanning to 3D printer

Tags: scanning

I have one `*.xyz` file (from a laser scan) that I wanted to mesh and create a 3D printable file.

I saw some YouTube videos from Meshlab and try to follow the steps explained in the video, [3D Laser Scanning - Meshing Point Clouds in Meshlab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPEQVBhKJGA&t=306s);

When I reached the step: "Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction I discovered that "Surface Reconstruction: Poisson" does not appear in my Meshlab (V2016.12).

I search on web to see if I could use another modelating method, but everybody said the «Poisson» method is the "one"!

I have two questions:

1. It is possible not have the "Surface Reconstruction: Poisson" in the program (there is something I need to pay for use it?);
2. Not having the "Surface Reconstruction: Poisson", is there any other possibility to create a surface from a xyz point cloud?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! This question, I think, covers your request a lot better than the [previous question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/9835/surface-reconstruction-poisson). Hopefully someone can help you get an answer.

Comment: What operating system are you running Meshlab on? This question may have your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428698/poisson-mesh-reconstruction

Comment: Jose,you seem to have to different accounts, would you like to have them merged?

Answer (score 3):

Same menu, different location in the sub-menu (at the bottom):

[image: Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction]

As [T.M.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users/13841/t-m) states in [their comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/9854/laser-scanning-to-3d-printer#comment16136_9854), see [Poisson mesh reconstruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428698/poisson-mesh-reconstruction) on StackOverflow:

> MeshLab 2016 now uses the new version of the Poisson merging, and the
>   filter is called:
>
> Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction
>
> it is in the same submenu, on the bottom. The relevant parameter
>   (octree depth) is called Reconstruction Depth. It is now possible to
>   merge multiple layers at once, without flattening them beforehand (as
>   before). If source layer(s) have color, the result will be colored
>   too. If you want to have the same result of the old version, put 0 in
>   the "interpolation weight" parameter